# MVC3 Appearing of confirmation message is increasing as geometric progression after each clicking

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a button. After first click I am getting "Button pressed!" confirmation message. When I press button again I am getting confirmation twice. After third press, message appears four time. In fact I am getting geometric progression. Please help.

View is.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
}
<div id="buttonPressed">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Button", "Index", new AjaxOptions { Confirm = "Button pressed!", UpdateTargetId = "buttonPressed" })
</div>
```

Controller is.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, that sounds like a linear progression.  Geometric would be 1, 2, 4, 8, ...

Comment: The problem is that you are updating the `div` that contains the button.

Comment: I have a label on the page and label value is being updated after each click. And when I do not contain action link in the div, label appears twice. That is why I am  containing action link in the div.

Answer (score 0):

When the post comes back you are replacing the contents of the buttonPressed div which contains the button itself.  Not a great thing to do.

In addition it is not proper to call back to the Index method which originally displayed the view.  That will re-render the page along with the html in the div with an entire rerendering of the view (including all master page stuff), which will continue to happen over and over again.

You need to change the action callback to another action method in your controller, then return a partialView of some html or a string or something else.